# sdk AutoML on Databricks

Tags: azure, automl, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run azureml-sdk AutoML on databricks to do a feature/model sweep on a classification task, and when I run the experiment I get the following error:

Running an experiment on spark cluster: ComputeAutoML.

```
ERROR: Setup iteration failed: {'exception': ValueError('dataprep_json is None')}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What is your cluster configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old SDK so upgrade to the latest SDK and pandas.
Tabular dataset need to be passed for X and y while running on ADB.
[image] 
[image]
Please follow the below notebook for running automl on databricks.
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/azure-databricks/automl/automl-databricks-local-01.ipynb